# Using the -Depth property of the Get-ChildItem Powershell cmdlet

Tags: powershell, get-childitem

I'm trying to use the -Depth parameter of the Get-Children cmdlet to find the shallower (less deep) of 2 files having the same name as shown below.

```
C:\temp\test.txt
C:\temp\Logs\test.txt
```

Many posts suggest defining -Path as "C:\temp\*" or "C:\temp\*\*".  But in my case I prefer to use the -Depth Parameter to limit the depth of recursions in the search.  I've read that it implies recursion and thus need not be used in conjunction with recurse.  So far I've tried all the commands below but they all return the same results shown further down.

```
Get-ChildItem -Path C:\temp -Depth 0 -Include tes*.txt | Format-List -Property FullName
Get-ChildItem -Path C:\temp -Depth 1 -Include tes*.txt | Format-List -Property FullName
Get-ChildItem -Path C:\temp -Depth 2 -Include tes*.txt | Format-List -Property FullName
Get-ChildItem -Path C:\temp -Depth 3 -Include tes*.txt | Format-List -Property FullName
Get-ChildItem -Path C:\temp -Depth '1' -Include tes*.txt | Format-List -Property FullName
Get-ChildItem -Path C:\temp -Depth "1" -Include tes*.txt | Format-List -Property FullName
Get-ChildItem -Path C:\temp -Depth $d -Include tes*.txt | Format-List -Property FullName
Get-ChildItem -Path C:\temp -Depth $d -Include tes*.txt -Recurse | Format-List -Property FullName
Get-ChildItem -Path C:\temp -Depth 0 -Include tes*.txt -Recurse | Format-List -Property FullName
Get-ChildItem -Path C:\temp -Depth 0 -Include tes*.txt -Recurse | Format-List -Property FullName
Get-ChildItem -Path C:\temp -Depth 2 -Include tes*.txt -Recurse | Format-List -Property FullName
Get-ChildItem -Path C:\temp -Depth 3 -Include tes*.txt -Recurse | Format-List -Property FullName
Get-ChildItem -Path C:\temp -Include tes*.txt -Depth 1 | Format-List -Property FullName
Get-ChildItem -Path C:\temp -Include tes*.txt -Depth 0 | Format-List -Property FullName
Get-ChildItem -Path C:\temp -File -Include tes*.txt -Depth 0 | Format-List -Property FullName
Get-ChildItem -Path C:\temp -File -Include tes*.txt -Depth 1 | Format-List -Property FullName
Get-ChildItem -Path C:\temp -File -Include tes*.txt -Depth 2 | Format-List -Property FullName
Get-ChildItem -Path C:\temp\* -Include tes*.txt -Recurse | Format-List -Property FullName
```

ALL of the commands above yield the same result, namely

```
FullName : C:\temp\Logs\test.txt
FullName : C:\temp\test.txt
```

Aside from the -Depth property, using the "\*" as many suggest enables me to isolate the deeper file but not the shallower file.  Am I missing something?

```
PS C:\>  Get-ChildItem -Path C:\temp\* -Include tes*.txt -Recurse | Format-List -Property FullName

FullName : C:\temp\Logs\test.txt
FullName : C:\temp\test.txt

PS C:\>  Get-ChildItem -Path C:\temp\*\* -Include tes*.txt -Recurse | Format-List -Property FullName

FullName : C:\temp\Logs\test.txt

PS C:\>  Get-ChildItem -Path C:\temp\*\*\* -Include tes*.txt -Recurse | Format-List -Property FullName

PS C:\>
```

Comment: I think you miss the -Recurse parameter in the first block of commands. When using the `\*\*` notation you can skip 'shallower' folders

Comment: from my testing _[on win7ps5.1]_ the `-Depth` parameter **_requires_** the `-Recurse` parameter and _forbids_ the `-Include` and the `-Exclude` parameters.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The usage of `-Depth` seems to exclude the usage of `-Include` or
even a wildcard in the `-Path` parameter.

Let `-Filter` do the work, in this sample tree:

```
> tree /F
C:.
└───temp
    │   Test.txt
    │
    └───0
        │   Test.txt
        │
        └───1
            │   Test.txt
            │
            └───2
                    Test.txt
```

This one liner:

```
 0..4|%{"-Depth $_ ---------------";(Get-ChildItem -Path C:\Temp\ -Depth $_ -Filter Tes*.txt).FullName}
```

returns:

```
-Depth 0 ---------------
C:\Temp\Test.txt
-Depth 1 ---------------
C:\Temp\Test.txt
C:\Temp\0\Test.txt
-Depth 2 ---------------
C:\Temp\Test.txt
C:\Temp\0\Test.txt
C:\Temp\0\1\Test.txt
-Depth 3 ---------------
C:\Temp\Test.txt
C:\Temp\0\Test.txt
C:\Temp\0\1\Test.txt
C:\Temp\0\1\2\Test.txt
-Depth 4 ---------------
C:\Temp\Test.txt
C:\Temp\0\Test.txt
C:\Temp\0\1\Test.txt
C:\Temp\0\1\2\Test.txt
```

Comment: Excellent code sample.  Thanks.  I can see now that I was using the -Include property when I should have been using -Filter.  The -Recurse flag was not required on my Win7 Pwsh 5.1 setup.

Answer (score 1):

When using `-include` as a filter, `-depth` seems to be ignored  (bug?) .

`-include` can be used to match multiple criteria.
Better use `-filter` if you have only one criteria and you want to limit search depth, or do multiple searches with single criteria.